# Convert Sys.time() to numeric and append to a string

Tags: r

I have used `as.numeric` to convert the `Sys.time()` to numeric and append with another string just to create a filename with that as below

```
as.numeric(Sys.time())
[1] 1547099793

paste0('filename',as.numeric(Sys.time()),".csv")
[1] "filename1547100543.00219.csv"" #It adds decimals
```

How to get the result as `'filename1547100543.csv'` and assign to a variable to create a file with the name? something like below

```
newfile=paste0('filename',as.numeric(Sys.time()),".csv")
fwrite(dt,paste(path,newfile))
```

Comment: Why are you not trying something like paste0('filename',strftime(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d"),".csv") Instead of converting the date as numeric value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `round` on the system time, to get a whole number:

```
paste0('filename',round(as.numeric(Sys.time())),".csv")

[1] "filename1547100986.csv"
```

**Alternative** : As suggested by @Ronak, use `as.integer` function instead so that you don't have to round it off to zero decimal place.

```
paste0('filename',as.integer(Sys.time()),".csv")
[1] "filename1547100986.csv"
```

Comment: or you could use `as.integer` instead `paste0('filename',as.integer(Sys.time()),".csv")`